# Alarm Manager Triggers Notification

Tags: android, alarm, notificationmanager

I have an alarm manager that triggers a notification every Sunday.  It works fine but whenever I open the application, the notification is displayed even if it is not Sunday.  Is the onReceive method triggered when the application opens?  How could I change it so the notification does not display when the app is opened?

CODE:

```
package com.sjjgames.abortionappnoads;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

                // Put here YOUR code.
                //NOTIFICATION
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Fetal Development")
                        .setContentText("Click here to view you child's development for this week!");
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, StatusOfChild.class);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(StatusOfChild.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(9011, mBuilder.build());

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         /*
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
         calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
         */
        long day = 0;
        Calendar dayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long dayOfWeek = dayCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (dayOfWeek == 1){ //Sunday
            day = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        if (dayOfWeek == 2){ //Monday
            day = 24*60*60*1000*2;
        }
        if (dayOfWeek == 3){ //Tuesday
            day = 24*60*60*1000*3;
        }
        if (dayOfWeek == 4){ //Wednesday
            day = 24*60*60*1000*4;
        }
        if (dayOfWeek == 5){ //Thursday
            day = 24*60*60*1000*5;
        }
        if (dayOfWeek == 6){ //Friday
            day = 24*60*60*1000*6;
        }
        if (dayOfWeek == 7){ //Saturday
            day = 24*60*60*1000;
        }
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, day, 24*60*60*1000*7, pi);

     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) will trigger the alarm immediately if it is in the past. You will need to compute the time difference then shedule the alarm. Adding to the calendar seems like an easy way to do it.

Eg, if you were using Calendar and the current day is Monday:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
         calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
         calendar.add (Calendar.DATE, 6); //add 6 days.
```

Comment: Will this work? If not how do I create a calendar which points to following Sunday? am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+(calendar.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis()), 24*60*60*1000*7, pi);

Comment: @Shane time differences are a tricky thing. I edited my answer since there is an easier way. I'd say play around with the calendar methods since all you're messing around with are the days.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my post to include my changes but I am still facing the original problem! I do not see why this code will not work...

Comment: You need to add, I am absolutely sure `24*60*60*1000*6` as a date has *already passed*. So `System.currentTimeMillis()+day` should work better.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I think it is finally working correctly!